# Datagridview math operation with next row data

Tags: c#, math, datagridview, rows, cells

I have datagridview with 7 columns. But its not bind to any database. Rows will be added from few textboxes line by line when i press the "Add" button on my form. But i have a problem with my 6th column data(Cells[5]).

current row 6th column data value = next row 2nd column value - current row 2nd column value

I can do this with excel very easily. but how can i do this on a datagridview? codes are welcome.

here is my code.

```
    private void FEAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int n = dgvFE.Rows.Add();
       dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
       dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = MtrtextBox1.Text.ToString();
       dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = PltrtextBox11.Text.ToString();
       dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = BvtextBox12.Text.ToString();

       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFE.Rows)
       {
           dgvFE.Rows[row.Index].Cells[2].Value = Math.Round((Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[row.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString()) / Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[row.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString())), 2).ToString();

           if (n >1)
           {
               dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1].Cells[5].Value = Math.Round((Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) - Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1].Cells[1].Value.ToString())), 2).ToString();
           }

       }

   }
```

I get below error,

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1]` throws exception for row №0. so add an index check

```
private void FEAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int n = dgvFE.Rows.Add();
   dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
   dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = MtrtextBox1.Text.ToString();
   dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = PltrtextBox11.Text.ToString();
   dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = BvtextBox12.Text.ToString();

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFE.Rows)
   {
       row.Cells[2].Value = Math.Round((Double.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()) / Double.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString())), 2).ToString();

       if (n > 0 && row.Index > 0)
       {
           dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1].Cells[5].Value = Math.Round((Double.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) - Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1].Cells[1].Value.ToString())), 2).ToString();
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: It worked when i enter 3rd row in data in to the dgv. why its not working when there is only two rows?

Comment: i updated my answer. change `n>1` to `n>0`. used your code here and didn't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 column and you write cells[5]. it must be cells[4].

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 5th column i mentioned here is cells[5]. Because i have 7 columns.

Comment: What about the Rows[row.Index-1]. for your first Row the index =0. row.Index-1 will be negative

Comment: First row cells[5] value can be null if there isn't a second row in dgv. It doesn't matter. If there is more than one row, i need to do the math which i mentioned above. Any luck with this?

Comment: But this line of code ( dgvFE.Rows[row.Index-1]) is the source of the ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You can't wirte Rows[something Negative]

Comment: add the condition if( Row.index>0)

Comment: Good @IshanSasanka. If my answer helps you check it as helpful. thanks